# Non Rectangular Layouts

Tags: html, css

I want to create HTML layout like this
https://dribbble.com/shots/2136656-Minions-Promo/attachments/393961

I tried to use some css codes to make elements non rectangular, but no luck so far :).

I saw this post:
[How can i Create This Non-Rectangular Layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249158/how-can-i-create-this-non-rectangular-layouts)
But couldn't find answers there :)

Anyone have an idea how to build this thing?

Thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, this is only shape, I need to have HTML elements and content inside this elements.

Comment: Adapt it, learn from it. There is all the information you need on this page.

Comment: I really tried, but nothing in this page helps me :)

Comment: How about this then. http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:pseudo` element to add a background and use `skew` property

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.red {
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.red:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(0deg, 2deg);
}
.blue {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
.blue:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(0deg, -2deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <h1>Sed augue ipsum egestas</h1>
  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Donec id justo. Praesent turpis.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero.</p>

  <p>Pellentesque posuere. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Quisque id mi.</p>
</div>


<div class="blue">
  <h1>Sed augue ipsum egestas</h1>
  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Donec id justo. Praesent turpis.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero.</p>

  <p>Pellentesque posuere. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Quisque id mi.</p>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.yellow {
  margin: 80px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.yellow:before,
.yellow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
.yellow:before {
  top: -40px;
  transform: skew(0, 3deg);
}
.yellow:after {
  bottom: -40px;
  transform: skew(0, -3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">Fusce fermentum odio nec arcu. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras varius. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Cras dapibus. Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Fusce a quam. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat feugiat, eros pede
  varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aliquam lobortis. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla.</div>
```

Comment: Actually it can be improve to be the shape like this?https://dribbble.com/shots/2136656-Minions-Promo/attachments/393961

Comment: check the 2nd snippet @Mosh

Comment: Ok, the first code is better, since the second, with the yellow class, make double skew, I need shape that is http://i.imgur.com/p3NiVA8.png

Comment: you can invert the skew property from +v to -v and -ve to +ve check the 2nd snippet